# Trying to read styleSheets returns undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, stylesheet

I've searched for an answer and no solution seems to fix this problem, so hopefully stating it specifically will help me find a solution.

I'm trying to read cssText of the first stylesheet using `document.styleSheets[0].cssText`, but it always returns `undefined`. I do have a stylesheet and it's visibly noticeable, but JavaScript doesn't seem to recognize it.

This did, however, work when I included the stylesheet within the page using `<style>`. I don't see why this would change when using `<link>`, though. Not only is it placed before the script, but it even returns `undefined` when using `javascript:alert(document.styleSheets[0].cssText)` in the omnibar after the page is fully loaded.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: This applies to **any** method with `document.styleSheets[0]`, including those of which are supposed to work on multiple browsers and have worked for me prior to using `<link>`. For example: `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].selectorText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html), `document.styleSheets[n].cssText` is only supported in IE.

The form

```
document.styleSheets[n].cssRules[m].cssText
```

seems to be more widely supported, so you could just loop over that and build a string from the individual rules. (Although you have to replace `cssRules` with `rules` for IE).

Comment: It worked when the `<style>` tag was used, though. Many of the samples on quirksmode also worked on my web browser.

Comment: I could of sworn it was supported by more than IE.

Answer (score 1):

I thing that this answer is out of time, but it could be useful for someone else.
The result can be "undefined" due 2 different reasons:

a) In some browsers, the property "cssRules" does not work (in accord with http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/cssrule.shtml, only for supported in NS/ Firefox). For the other browser, you should use the property "rules", instead.

You can solve the problem using something like:

```
if (document.styleSheets[0].cssRules)
    crossrule=document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0]
else if (document.styleSheets[0].rules)
    crossrule=document.styleSheets[0].rules[0]
```

to extract the rule and, afterwards, to extract the name of selector:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].selectorText
```

b) After the overpassing of the issue a), you may have another problem: The rules that starts with a @, like @import of @font-face, as considered as rules. However, their "selectorText" is undefined. So, you must have a way of skip them. I am working on it, right now. But I have not found yet a solution. Anyway, it is an help to know way it is happening.

Hope this helps